# jquery mobile panel ONLY on the first page doesn't work after first time

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've seen a lot of topics on the panel element of JQM, but I don't see anything similar so here's the question.

I have different pages (with different ids), each with its own panel element:

```
<!-- MAIN MENU -->
<div id="mainmenu" data-role="panel">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="list.html">Happiness Diary</a></li>
    [...]
  </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="header">...</div>
<div data-role="content">...</div>
<div data-role="footer">...</div>
```

And the `swiperight` event bound to call the a function with the following code:

```
showMenu: function() {
  console.log("showmenu active page is: " + $.mobile.activePage.attr("id"));
  $.mobile.activePage.find('#mainmenu').panel("open");
},
```

Now, for all the other pages the navigation is OK and the panel works without problems.
The only problem I have is when I go back to index.html (the first page loaded, page with id `mainpage`).
It's strange because I see the code executed correctly: `showmenu active page is: mainpage`, but the panel is not shown.

Any hints?

**UPDATE:** Just to test, I've created a new entry page, so index.html is not anymore the first page loaded. In this way the panel in index.html works correctly. It was just to completely exclude some unexpected behaviors related to the page. So the problem is exactly that it's the first page loaded.

Thanks,
  Lorenzo

Comment: how do you go back to *index.html* and where do you have all js libraries loaded?

Comment: I go back to index.html using the link that you see in the code.
For the javascript libraries, I have them splitted just after the div with page role, only the common ones (jquery mobile, cordova, and similar) are inside the `<head>` tag.

Comment: But seriously it doesn't seem a problem related on how the scripts are loaded, the correct function is called and the active page is correct. BUT the panel is not shown

Comment: do you navigate away with the panel open? does it happen on all pages or only mainpage?

Comment: I've tried every possible combination (panel closed or opened and navigate to different pages).
The problem is only with the mainpage.

Example: let's say I have the pages `mainpage`, `elist`, `estats`.
 1) First load, mainpage shown: panel works (close/open all the time you want);
 2) I change page, I go to elist. Panel works.
 3) I go to estats, Panel works.
 4) Repeat 2) and 3) how many times you want, it works.
 5) Go back in mainpage: doesn't work anymore.

Another interesting thing is that if I go again to another page, in that page the panel works. it's only mainpage the problem

Comment: I try to add some details to give additional infos:

- there aren't duplicated ids;
- it doesn't matter from which page I come from, the problem in mainpage it's there;
- The HTML page is validated correctly from the W3C tool, Javascript is valid too and there aren't errors in the console

Comment: try `$('#mainmenu').panel("open");` without `$.mobile.activePage....`

Comment: Thanks Omar, I've tried but in this way it doesn't work on every page.
I've tried even to apply a class to the panel and change to code to $('.theclass').panel("open"). It's a terrible solution because calls a function on every panel in the DOM, but even like this doesn't work, with the same behavior of the .ativePage.find(....).panel("open"). I don't know what else to try :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I created three basic pages to test with. This is the structure of the pages:

```
<div data-role="page" id="example_page_one" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
    <div id="example_page_one_menu" data-role="panel">
        <ul>
            <li class="home"><a href="index.htm" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.htm">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header">Header Content</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>This is the content for example page one!</p>
        <p><a href="javascript: showMenu();">Open the menu panel</a></p>
        <p>A link to <a href="sandbox_m2.php">example page two</a></p>
        <p>A link to <a href="sandbox_m3.php">example page three</a></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">Footer Content</div>
</div>
```

Notice that the panel id value is the same as the page id value but has `_menu` appended. This naming scheme is expected by the reworked `showMenu` function (shown further below).

Pages two and three are the same except the page and panel id's are changed replacing `one` for `two` and `three` respectively for each page. (The links in the content area are adjusted to point to the other two example pages as well.)

I have the following function in the `<head>...</head>` section of all pages:

```
function showMenu(){
    console.log("showMenu active page is: " + $.mobile.activePage[0].id );
    $('#'+$.mobile.activePage[0].id+'_menu').panel("open");
}
```

You'll notice in the code above that `.find('#mainmenu')` is not necessary, because we are able to target the panel by it's unique id. I also found a post that suggested the use of `[0].id` as being more efficient than `.attr['id']`.

I just use a simple link in the content area of each page to call the `showMenu` function. You can bind your swipe event to call the `showMenu` function, I just did it this way to keep things simple.

Anyway, the panel works fine on the first page loaded and subsequent pages. Your question doesn't clarify if you are using the same panel id value for all panels in each page or not. I do want to point out that I am using different id values for each panel.

The other thing I noticed while playing around is that there is a [bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3384) as to when `activePage` is available which may or may not be related to your issue.

**Original Answer**

I have noticed that JavaScript code placed in a page `<div>` section is only loaded/executed ONCE EVER for the first page that is loaded in a JQM site and never again within the same session. However, any JavaScript code in the page `<div>` section for any other page EXCEPT the first one loaded will execute every time.

I don't put JavaScript code in the page `<div>` anymore and instead use the `pageshow` or `pageinit` events depending on what I am doing.

The following shows example code that, when used, would be placed in the `<head>...</head>` section of every page (AFTER the jQuery library is loaded and BEFORE the jquery-mobile library is loaded):

```
<script>
    $(document).on("pageshow", "#specific_page_id", function() {
        // .. Do stuff *every time* the '#specific_page_id' is loaded/displayed
    });
    $(document).on("pageshow", function() {
        // .. Do stuff *every time* ANY page is loaded/displayed
    });
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#specific_page_id", function() {
        // .. Do stuff only when'#specific_page_id' is initially loaded
        //    (will also fire if the specific page was previously loaded but it is no longer in the JQM cache)
    });
    $(document).on("pageinit", function() {
        // .. Do stuff when any page is initially loaded
        //    (Will not fire for previously loaded pages that are still in the JQM cache)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Drew.
Anyway, as I wrote before, it's not a problem related to events fired or not, because I can see that I reach the function `showMenu()`, and I see the message printed on the console with the statement `console.log("showmenu active page is: " + $.mobile.activePage.attr("id"));`. So, the events/callbacks stuff works correctly AND the activePage id is correct. But the panel is never visualized :\

Comment: for now thanks for you kindness trying all of this.
I've currently moved a bit something, the entry page is not anymore the same so the problem is less relevant now. BUT I will try and eventually accept your answer, even if it's more a workaround (working with activePage has to work, right? :) ). Thank you.