# JQuery Mobile Panel not working navigating back to first page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am hit with an issue which is blocking me now. I have a panel which can be opened from all my pages and I am using External Panel ( new in JQM 1.4.0) to achieve this which is pretty cool. Panel has links to different pages which are used for navigation. Everything was working fine, until I changed all the transition: 'slide' to transition:'none' for some obvious performance reasons. After I removed the transition Panel started to give weird problems

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TAS25/36/) for better understanding. Open the panel by clicking the 'Menu' button, click on the 'Go to Page Two' link. This will call a JS method from where I use changePage to pageTwo (I should go through JS method as per design, I can't go like #pageTwo). Now click on Back button to go back to #pageOne. Now if you click on the Menu button it doesn't open. Surprisingly, this whole thing works if I use **any transition**** while doing changePage to pageTwo, ie if i use below code this works fine.

```
  $.mobile.changePage('#pageTwo', {transtion,'slide'})
```

I found a similiar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466036/jquery-mobile-panel-only-on-the-first-page-doesnt-work-after-first-time), but there is no solution. Any help is appreciated

Comment: as this could be a bug in jQM, a workaround might be to set a really fast transition time via CSS. Here is your updated fiddle with refactored code and the CSS to speed up the fade: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/TAS25/37/ (also you should use jQuery 1.10.x with jQM 1.4...

Comment: Thanks for the hint @ezanker. I used your point to make a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick work around for this issue. The issue happens when we do a change page, page changes before the panel could close. So I gave a delay before calling change page.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.changePage('#page2',{transtion:'none'});   
},200);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's looks like a bug in JQM 1.4,

`$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';` is causing it, although it shouldn't.

when page transition is set to none, page changes before panel is closed.

use
`$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'fade'; OR transition: "fade"`.

Comment: Hi @Beginner, Thanks for  the quick help. As I told I won't be able to  use transitions since its degrading the performance on lower devices. Also your solution works great when navigating through link on the panel. But when you go back to page1 from the link provided on page2 (in your fiddle), the Panel refuses to open.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I solved it by creating a script that listens on every page and delete the external panel before page will hide, something like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforehide', function(event)
{ 
    $('#mypanel').remove();
});
```

This script MUST be called before jquery mobile in your html file.

When you add a panel via JS to the DOM every time each page being open you also need to remove it before the current page will hide and than read it again on next page during navigation.

This works for me. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: thanks for the help @Ed .. I did another work around for this issue. Please see the below answer.

Comment: @hashcoder I'm glad you solved your problem, but this actually isn't my answer. I just [**edited**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated here: [Issue #7711 on Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7711)

It is now working with jQuery Mobile 1.4.5. I had the same problem and I upgraded to this version. It works for me!